# How do I change my x labels angle with swiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Im beginner in swiftUI
I would like to change the rotation of my values in the x-axis as shown in this image
[Desire chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yqms.png)
I currently have it like this in my code

```
Chart{
                    ForEach(arregloDummy) { arregloDummy in
                        LineMark(
                            x: .value("Periodo", arregloDummy.periodo.orEmpty),
                            y: .value("Consumo", arregloDummy.consumo ?? 0.0))
                    }
                }.frame(height: 200)
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(Color(cgColor: ColorSet.accentColor.cgColor))
                    .background(Color(red: 213 / 255, green: 218 / 255, blue: 198 / 255))
                    .chartYAxis{
                        AxisMarks(position: .leading)
                    }
```

an this is how it appears:
[Current chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQfu4.png)

I tried to use .rotationEffect, but it rotates my entire chart.

Comment: You can format your code in Xcode by selecting it and pressing `ctrl-i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `.chartXAxis` to customize the labels. If the values are `Int` then it might look something like:

```swift
    Chart {
        // Content as before
    }
    .chartXAxis {
        AxisMarks(position: .bottom, values: .automatic) { value in
            AxisValueLabel() {
                if let intValue = value.as(Int.self) {
                    Text("\(intValue)")
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(-35))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That worked, but some data doesn't display right, like it doesn't fit. It appears like

"202...
2022
2023
2024
202..."

Comment: It would help to know what the exact values are that you are trying to display. But now that you can customize the labels, you can tweak the way they are displayed in all sorts of other ways too. For example, try setting a smaller font, or use the modifier ```.fixedSize()```.